# Does JSSE use a certificate in a PrivateKeyEntry as a trust anchor?

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, truststore, jsse

If a key store containing one or more `PrivateKeyEntry` is specified as a trust store, will JSSE create a trust anchor from the end-entity certificate in each of those entries?

In other words, is it enough to have a certificate under a `PrivateKeyEntry` if we have one keystore with both trusted and private entries? Or, must we also add that certificate as a `TrustedCertificateEntry`?

Comment: You should describe the scenario a but more in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter where certificate placed either under **PrivateKeyEntry** or  under **trustedCertEntry** , JVM **trusts** host from certificate anyway.

Tested locally.

Run local server with https and keystore with **only one PrivateKeyEntry**.

And run client with code :

```
public static String getHTML(String urlToRead) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    URL url = new URL(urlToRead);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();
    return result.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String testUrl="https://localhost/test";
    System.out.println(getHTML(testUrl));
}
```

Without any:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

With **truststore** that contains only one **PrivateKeyEntry** (the same jks file that was used for server as keystore):

```
<!DOCTYPE....</html>
```

Comment: This is completely incorrect. It does matter. Java trusts `trustCertEntry` for incoming certificates, and uses `privateKeyEntry` for *outgoing* certicifates.

Comment: EJP, It doesn't matter why do we need to use one keystore with both, before I always had two... But now it's only one , actually that's why this question appear...I also thought always like you about it, but it's not true , test shows that server can has only one PrivateKeyEntry and it will be enough to trust. ..

Comment: It will be enough for the server to provide its certificate to clients. Whether they trust it is a completely separate matter, and it won't enable the servr to trust any certificates either if it is using that KeyStore as its truststore. Obviously you haven't tried this, or possibly you haven't understood your own question.

Comment: I understood my question. Just recheked. Ran jboss with https (PrivateKeyEntry) . And run another program with with truststore with one PrivateKeyEntry and it works...

Comment: I know that it's stupid things and far from being best practice , but it works ...

Comment: Your so-called proof isn't clear. Either you didn't have a server private key or you've got the private key of the server in the client's truststore. Both situations are invalid.

Comment: EJP, I have got the private key of the server in the client's truststore as PrivateKeyEntry.  Test completly correct. The question was : "Is it enough to have certificate under PrivateKeyEntry  to trust such service", the answer is yes.

Comment: Then you have committed a **major** security breach. The private key of the server is, err, private, and should not have been leaked to the client. Clearly what has happened is that the cliejt has sent the server's own certificate back to it as the client certificate. The situation is wrong wrong wrong. Don't do this.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it enough to have certificate under PrivateKeyEntry if we have one keystore with both trusted and private entries

You should never have such a keystore.

> or shall we add also certificate as trustedCertEntry in order to make requests to themself/other node under proxy ?

A `trustedCertEntry` is used for *incoming* certificates. A private key entry is used for *outgoing* certificates.

You're conflating two different things, indeed two different uses of keystores.

1. A keystore file that contains `trustedCertEntry` is a *truststore*, in the sense of `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`, and it tells JSSE which *incoming* certificates to trust, directly or indirectly.
2. A keystore file that contains `PrivateKeyEntry` is a *keystore*, in the sense of `javax.net.ssl.keyStore`, and it tells JSSE which certificates to use for *outbound* certificates.
3. A keystore file that contains both is radically malformed. A truststore is simply a list of certificates to be trusted. It isn't secret. A KeyStore contains your private key and it is top secret to everybody. Conflating the two is a major security breach.

If it doesn't matter why would there two different types of entry?

It's not even a proper question to ask. If you have a private key where a trusted certificate should be, that means you have someone else's private key, which is a *prima facie* security breach.

Comment: edited answer. Do you know that java supports also pkcs12 keystore format, maybe that's why it doesn't check is it trustedCertEntry or not... As pkcs12 doesn't have trustedCertEntry.

Comment: It may not be wise, but Java `KeyStore` API and its providers definitely support having trustedCert and PrivateKey entries in the same store, and for some types (at least JCEKS and BKS) SecretKey entries also; the privatekey *part* (or secretkey) is encrypted and not inherently breached. And if used as truststore, it *does* include the first (entity) cert of a PrivateKeyEntry; see http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/security/validator/KeyStores.java in method getTrustedCerts() .

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Of course it does, inevitably. I don't understand your last sentence. A trust tor contains certificates: I don't see what's noteworthy about that.

Comment: You say a PrivateKey entry "is used for outgoing certs", which is quite true; but if you have a PrivateKey entry in your truststore, which Java does allow, it uses chain[0] of the PrivateKey entry _also_ as a trust anchor for incoming certs, as the self-answer says. Normally this doesn't matter since it rarely makes sense for the other party to be using your own cert, or a cert that is under your own cert -- but it is possible, and IMO 'noteworthy' because it is likely to surprise people; it certainly seems to have surprised you.

Comment: @user207421 PrivateKeyEntry is a public/private key pair ? or how is it possible to use keytool -export to export the public certificate from this kind of entry ? thanks

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Not just surprised, astonished. Never seen that documented anywhere. It may be an empirical fact but if so an unspecified one.

Comment: @DiegoRamos Have you considered consulting the Javadoc for [PrivateKeyEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry.html) or the [keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html)? It's a lot more efficient than asking quesitons in comments on 5-year-old answers.

Comment: @user207421 yes I did but I got this from keytool: key entries--each holds very sensitive cryptographic key information, which is stored in a protected format to prevent unauthorized access.  Typically,  a  key  stored  in
            this  type of entry is a secret key, or a private key accompanied by the certificate "chain" for the corresponding public key. The keytool and jarsigner(1) tools only han-
            dle the latter type of entry, that is, private keys and their associated certificate chains.

Comment: @user207421 but it doesn't say if it also contains the public key, I mean it is not very Clear if a PrivateKeyEntry contains the pair (public and private keys) or only the private key

Comment: @DiegoRamos It is extremely clear that the `PrivateKey` part only contains the private key. The end certificate contains the public key.