# Can I use the same self signed certificate for client and server Java SSL

Tags: java, security, ssl, networking, jsse

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -keystore selfsigned.jks -validity <days> -keysize 2048
```

I generated a keystore using this.

Can I use this same keystore for both the client and server like below?

Client

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "herong.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "HerongJKS");
```

Server

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "herong.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "HerongJKS");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not if you want it secure. You've leaked the server's private key to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason why you can't use the same keystore on both the client and the server.

It only depends on your use case if it is wise to do so.

BTW: I think you misunderstood the concept of truststore and  keystore. They both are present for every jre.
The only difference between them is *what* they store. (Public keys of trusted CAs for the truststore, and all other public and private keys for the keystore)

Comment: The certificate is supposed to uniquely identify the peer. A shared KeyStore cannot accomplish that. It also violates private key privacy.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't 'us[ing] the same ... certificate for client and server', you are using the same *JKS file* for the server *keystore* and the client *truststore*, which are different things with different purposes.

Java does allow truststore to contain a privatekey entry (or entries) and uses the leaf cert in that entry(ies) as trust anchor(s); see [Does JSSE use a certificate in a PrivateKeyEntry as a trust anchor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36576061/does-jsse-use-a-certificate-in-a-privatekeyentry-as-a-trust-anchor)

This does make it easier to leak your privatekey and make your system insecure. It is much better practice to extract the server's anchor cert, which for a self-signed cert is the cert itself, and put only the cert (not the privatekey) in the client's truststore.